# Splunk Enterprise HEC not sending data

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I've installed the **Splunk Enterprise trial**. I've enabled the **HTTP Event Collector** feature as described [here](http://dev.splunk.com/view/event-collector/SP-CAAAE7F) which enables sending machine data from my app into Splunk.

I tried to send a **POST** request using **Postman** to **Splunk** and got no response.

```
method: POST
url : http://localhost:8088/services/collector
Authorization : my generated token
```

1. Why there is no response if I already enabled the HEC feature? It seems that no server listens on that port at all.
2. What I don't understand about Splunk is -- **where is my data stored**? Is data for Splunk Enterprise stored only locally and should be in use inside companies **LAN** network? Or Splunk's own servers in the cloud that stored all my data? Are **Splunk Enterprise** and **Splunk Cloud** different on that subject?

Comment: Splunk Enterprise stores data locally, on your server; Splunk Cloud stores data in the cloud.

Comment: Do you get a 401 code when you try to send your data?

Comment: thank for the support.
No i'm getting an empty response

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices, send JSON data using HEC event data format specification for ex.

```
curl -k "https://mysplunkserver.example.com:8088/services/collector" \
-H "Authorization: Splunk CF179AE4-3C99-45F5-A7CC-3284AA91CF67" \
-d '{"event": "Hello, world!", "sourcetype": "manual"}'
```

Or send raw data, for this you need to use the raw endpoint, for ex.

```
curl -k
"https://mysplunkserver.example.com:8088/services/collector/raw?channel=00872DC6- 
AC83-4EDE- -H "Authorization: Splunk CF179AE4-3C99-45F5-A7CC-3284AA91CF67" -d '1,
2, 3... Hello, world!'
```